# Patterns to implement this grammar into C# code

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dsl

Hey guys, I'm creating this little BNF grammar and I wanted to

```
<template>::= <types><editors>
<types>::= <type>+
<type>::= <property>+
<property>::= <name><type>
<editors>::= <editor>+
<editor>::= <name><type>(<textfield>|<form>|<list>|<pulldown>)+
<textfield>::= <label><property>[<editable>]
<form>::= <label><property><editor>
<list>::= <label><property><item-editor>
<pulldown>::= <label><property><option>+
<option>::= <value>
```

One possible solution we have in mind is to create POCO's that have annotations of the XMLSerialization namespace, like this, for example:

```
[XMLRoot("template")]
public class Template{ 
    [XMLElement("types")]        
    public Types types{

    }
}
```

However I want to explore more solutions, what do you guys think?

Comment: I don't see the question? You wanted to what?

Comment: Couple Questions:
What are the whitespace rules for this language? 
What are the terminals?
Is this only going to be XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this by yourself, look at Interpreter Design Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a specific input of some complexity, use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org). See [C# instructions](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target) to get started.